# Unity Gizmos for arraylist

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, unity-game-engine

How can i apply Gizmos to parallel arrays of positions ?
The current code i have now is that, the Gizmos does its job.
But since its a loop, it flashes which means going through the loop and drawing an array using the method

```
Gizmos.DrawRay();
```

But i don't want it to go through the loop and draw a ray and then removing it and repeating the process with a new position.
I want it to draw a ray for every element in the array and have the ray fixed where it doesn't get rewritten.
So here is my current code.

**Edit :**

```
void Platform_Position_Scale_Generator(int i) {

    posX[i] = Random.Range(minPosRange, maxPosRange + 1);
    posY[i] = Random.Range(minPosRange, maxPosRange + 1);
    posZ[i] = 0;

    scaleX[i] = Random.Range(minScaleRange, maxScaleRange + 1);
    scaleY[i] = 1;
    scaleZ[i] = 1;

}

void Platform_Generator(int i) {

    platformPrefabPosition[i].x = posX[i];
    platformPrefabPosition[i].y = posY[i];
    platformPrefabPosition[i].z = posZ[i];

    Instantiate(platformPrefab, platformPrefabPosition[i], Quaternion.identity);
    platformPrefab.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scaleX[i], 1, 1);


}

void OnDrawGizmos() {
    if(numOfGeneratedPlatforms < numOfPlatformsToGenerate) {
        Platform_Position_Scale_Generator(numOfGeneratedPlatforms);
        Platform_Generator(numOfGeneratedPlatforms);

        Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
        Gizmos.DrawRay(new Vector3((posX[numOfGeneratedPlatforms]), (posY[numOfGeneratedPlatforms]), (posZ[numOfGeneratedPlatforms])), transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.up));
        numOfGeneratedPlatforms++;

    }
}
```

Comment: In your title you said you use an ArrayList(?) but in your description you call it arrays. The ArrayList class should be avoided since it's untyped. Also when working with positions you usually would use one array or List which contains Vector3s.

Could you include the declaration of your posX, posY and posZ array / collection? I think that would make the question a bit clearer

Comment: So like, when i mean array list i mean like parallel arrays.
posX[], posY[], posZ[]

Answer (score 0):

Unity as well as the SceneView need to redraw the whole area everytime something changes. There is no way to draw something that will stay. If you want it to stay you have to redraw it every time the SceneView is redrawn. Unlike at runtime, at edittime Unity only redraws a window when some event happened.

So if you want to have a line for each position you have to draw a line for each position in OnDrawGizmos, everytime it's called. The SceneView works the same as the GameView. However it uses an invisible camera to render the scene from the editors perspective. Each time it is redrawn the SceneView will be cleared and completely redrawn. During that process Unity will call your OnDrawGizmos method where you have to draw everything you want to be visible in the scene.

***edit***

To draw all lines for all elelments you just have to use a loop, like this:

```
void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
    for(int i = 0; i < posX.Length; i++)
    {
        Gizmos.DrawRay(new Vector3(posX[i], posY[i], posZ[i]), transform.up);
    }
}
```

This will draw a one unit long line from each point in your list upwards. As i said if you work with positions it's usually way easier to work with a single array and use Vector3 has type:

```
public Vector3[] positions;
```

Or if you have to add / remove items quite often, use a generic List:

```
public List<Vector3> positions
```

ps: To me it looks a bit strage that you want to draw a line upwards. If you wanted to draw a line from point to point, you have to do:

```
void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
    // important to reduce the upper limit by one since we add 1 inside the loop
    for(int i = 0; i < posX.Length-1; i++)
    {
        Gizmos.DrawLine(
            new Vector3(posX[i], posY[i], posZ[i]),
            new Vector3(posX[i+1], posY[i+1], posZ[i+1])
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think i get what you mean by redrawing itself.
But right now , i want to draw it for every item in my parallel arrays.
So how can i do that ?

Comment: Oh thanks man .. thats what i wanted.
But umm . . i was just wondering.
How would you apply overlapSphere for this ?
Because i want to detect when there is an overlap of platforms.

Comment: @JekasG: Well, OverlapSphere only works with colliders. If your platforms have colliders you can use it, even in the editor. However this question was about drawing lines and gizmos. I suggest to create a new question and include more details about what you want to do. If you are new to Q&A sites please take a look at [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help)